# COUNTIF and SUM in Excel with different ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

Is there a more efficient way of making the following function?:

```
>=COUNTIF(A1,">0")+COUNTIF(C1,">0")+COUNTIF(E1,">0")+COUNTIF(G1,">0")
```

I want to count if the cell is bigger than 0 and sum it. This function gets long and complicated if there are more than 3 cells with different ranges that I want to count.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the cell is not blank or if the cell contains a number that is greater than 0?  Your current formula will count the number of cells that have values greater than zero.

Comment: There are possibly negatives in these cells? Because if you can change your formula to display zeroes when the result is negative, then a regular sum function will only add the positive values anyway. For instance if A1=3-7 you could wrap it with =MAX(0,A1) which will convert it to zero. But you may still want to see the negatives so not sure if that will work for you

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to count every other cell (cell with an odd column index) with value greater than zero:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(A1:Q1),2)=1)*(A1:Q1<>"")*(A1:Q1>0))
```

This will do it for range `A1:Q1`, counting cells A1, C1, E1, G1, I1, K1, M1, O1, Q1 with value >0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sum the cells that have a number greater than zero.  If that is the case use this formula.

```
=SUMIFS(A1:C1,A1:C1,">0")
```

If you want to count the number of cells that with values greater than zero use this formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:C1,">0")
```

Comment: I want to count the numbers of cells with values greater than zero, so the function 
=COUNTIFS(A1:C1,">0")
is good, but the tricky part is the range. I want to count alternate columns cells. That would be A1, C1, E1, skipping one column each time.